# Sum of a given number

Tags: c#, loops

The sum of the given number is 107,

At the first iteration the sum is 56,

I don't get it , why ?

At the end the sum suppose to be 11.

```
 Console.WriteLine(sumTheNum(83));

   private static int sumTheNum(int number)
    {
        string numbersToSum = number.ToString();
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersToSum.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += (int)numbersToSum[i];
        }
  
        return sum;
    }
```

I know this not the correct solution for this porpuse, but I just stuck first with the sum.
I'm only at the beginning.

Comment: `(int)numbersToSum[i]` will not be the value of the digits, it will be the ascii decimal value of the characters.

Answer (score 4):

A better way to sum the digits of an `int` is to not convert back and forth to a string

```
private static int sumTheNum(int number)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while(number != 0)
    {
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Here `number % 10` will get the last digit of the number and `number /= 10;` will truncate the last digit.  So you'll have summed all the digits once `number = 0`.

Note that if the number is negative it will still sum the digits, but the result will be negative like for -11 the result would be -2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
sum += (int)numbersToSum[i];
```

Unfortunately, casting a `char` to an `int`, in this case, results in you getting the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value rather than the value of the text. (in this case, the 8 character has an ASCII value of 56 and the 3 character has an ASCII value of 51, hence the sum of 107). You should do:

```
sum += int.Parse(numbersToSum[i].ToString());
```

instead.

Comment: fwiw, C#/.Net characters are UTF-16, not ASCII. But the values happen to be the same for the digit characters. Also, for this particular problem `int.Parse()` is needlessly slow.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hi Joel and thanks, for the knowledge, any idea what would be faster than `int.Parse()`?

Comment: @Ileh Generally, `int.Parse()` is the fastest **safe** option. But for this specific situation, where you ***know*** you have single digits, you can do something like `numbersToSum[i] - '0'`